# Why do I always get the error "vmError: Restricted access for view" on VirtueMart?

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I have a VirtueMart store hosted on Joomla.

Whenever I try to access the page frontend page for product management I get the errors "vmError: Restricted access for view 0" and "vmError: Restricted access for view product".

After that I get similar errors on the other pages of the store. I have to wait a few minutes without changing pages or refreshing before the errors go away.

If I access only the others pages apart from the product management one, no errors appear.

Where do I go to give the user the proper access authorizations? I've tried changing the permissions of the files themselves on CPanel but that didn't work. I've also tried changing the access levels for the various Joomla users without luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.